# How to read XML input in lstopo

Tags: images, conversion, xml, png

I have an XML output file from the `lstopo` command and I wanted to build a PNG file for it. Can I do this using the command line? Something like:

```
lstopo -i out.xml -o abc.png
```

Is something like this possible?

Comment: Have you tried `lstopo --input out.xml --output-format png abc.png`? (You may be able to leave out the `--output-format png`. [XML support must have been compiled into `hwloc` for the `--input` option to be usable.](https://linux.die.net/man/1/lstopo))

Comment: You're welcome.  Since it worked, I posted it as an answer (with a few extra words).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to build a PNG file
(containing a graphic rendering of your topology)
from your XML file (which was created by `lstopo`) with the command

```
lstopo --input out.xml --output-format png abc.png
```

In fact, it may be good enough to say

```
lstopo  -i out.xml  abc.png
```

because `lstopo` should assume that the output format is PNG
if the output filename has a `.png` extension (a.k.a. suffix),
and `--input` can be abbreviated to `-i`.

XML support must have been compiled into `hwloc`
for the `--input` option to be usable. 
See the [lstopo man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/lstopo) (and, if necessary, the pages it links to)
for more information.